# inequality for lengths of projections inside a circle

Tags: geometry

In the following picture, how can show that $c \leq a + b$?

[image: projections between points on a circle]

In the picture, $x$, $y$ and $z$ are three vectors of equal length.  We can split $x$ in a component parallel to $y$ and a component orthogonal to $y$.  The value $a$ is the length of the orthogonal component.  Similarly, we can split $z$ into components parallel and orthogonal to $y$, and $b$ is the length of the orthogonal component.  Finally, we can split $z$ into components parallel and orthogonal to $x$, and $c$ is the length of this orthogonal component.  (In the definition of $c$, we can swap the roles of $x$ and $z$, and get the same value $c$.)

While the picture is two-dimensional, I suspect the statement is true for $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}^d$ for and $d\geq 2$.  I would be happy with a proof for $d=2$, but even happier about a proof which can also cover the case $d>2$.

Comment: Brief comment: "flattening" any arrangement of three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ by rotating $x$ about $y$ until $x, y, z$ are coplanar will lengthen $c$ while keeping $a$ and $b$ the same, and any three vectors in $\mathbb{R}^d$ define a subspace of at most dimension $3$, so proving the two-dimensional case is sufficient.

Comment: (Should read: "until $x, y, z$ are coplanar and $y$ is between $x$ and $z$"; sorry. And I'm not sure that in the three-dimensional case, both lines marked as $c$ have equal length.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $\theta$ and $\phi$ be the angles between $x$ and $y$ and between $y$ and $z$ respectively, and letting $x$, $y$, and $z$ have equal length $1$, we have:
\begin{align*}
a &= \sin \theta \\
b &= \sin \phi \\
c &= \sin (\theta + \phi)
\end{align*}
and $c < a + b$ follows from the fact that $\sin x$ is sublinear for $x \in [0, \pi]$. (Alternatively, note that $c = \sin (\theta + \phi) = \sin \theta \cos \phi + \sin \phi \cos \theta < a+b$ because $\cos \theta$ and $\cos \phi$ are each less than $1$.)

Comment: I agree, this seems to work if $x$, $y$ and $z$ are arranged as in the picture.  But does this really cover all possible arrangements?  What if $z$ is between $x$ and $y$?  What if $\theta+\phi > \pi$?

Comment: Whether this works if either $\theta$ or $\phi$ exceeds $\pi/2$ depends on how you define signed lengths, I believe.

Comment: $a$, $b$ and $c$ in the question are meant to be positive.  So "signed lengths" may be part of the proof, but they are not part of the statement.